# Merge background with overlay of LaTeX text

Tags: pdf, overlays

I am interested in using Scribus (or similar) to create a background upon which the PDF output from Latex could be overlain. Is there a method to merge a PDF or image background with the PDF output of LaTeX?

Comment: I think with InkScape.

Comment: Oh, OK---I will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: I have virtually no experience with Inkscape, but yes----I was able to create a layered PDF which retains the resolution of the originals, and was able to alter the opacity of the underlying image. Now.....any ideas on how to automate this process, to put the background under multiple PDF pages that already exist as a single document

Comment: The `background` package would be a more obvious choice than Inkscape if you're asking about layering it behind LaTeX output. Inkscape would be better for creating the background, which may be what @Sebastiano had in mind.

Comment: Thanks! I was totally unaware of the 'Background' package, and will test-drive it very soon!